# Creating a circle around fa icons

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys I am trying to create a circle around my fa icons , example of this :

[image]

I have made everything apart from the circle border and i have no idea how to get this effect to work , i have this so far :

HTML:

```
<div class="row icon-set">
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
        <p>
            <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
        </p>
        <p class="title"><span class="underline-text">Awesome</span>
        </p>
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parrlex1 .underline-text {
    border-color: rgba(239,239,239,.5);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.parrlex1 .title {
    color: #ccb08a;
    margin-top: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.icon-set .fa-lightbulb-o {
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

The only part i cant get to work is the radius around the icon

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably better to style a parent container than the icon itself (see icon-container class). I moved the width, height, and border radius to the parent container and then used translate to center the icon in the circle. Hope this helps!

```css
.underline-text {
  border-color: rgba(239, 239, 239, .5);
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.title {
  color: #ccb08a;
  margin-top: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.icon-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.icon-set .fa-lightbulb-o {
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="row icon-set">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <p class="icon-container">
      <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
    </p>
    <p class="title"><span class="underline-text">Awesome</span>
    </p>
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help, also was in the middle of the circle so that was perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a class of `circle` around your containers and the CSS has been demonstrated below. Hope, this helps :)

```css
.parrlex1 .underline-text {
  border-color: rgba(239, 239, 239, .5);
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.parrlex1 .title {
  color: #ccb08a;
  margin-top: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.circle {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:1px solid gold;
  background-color: rgba(10,10,10,0.8);
  color: gold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.icon-set .fa-lightbulb-o {
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="row icon-set">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <p class="circle">
      <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
    </p>
    <p class="title"><span class="underline-text">Awesome</span>
    </p>
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```